# netty different channelpool and exception process

Tags: error-handling, netty, channel

I am new to `netty` and I have a problem using my `netty` program.

1. in `initConnection` method I want to make a different `channelpool` for each group. 
    
   when user group A come in my `sendToMessage` I want to create `channelPool A` 
   like this way  user group B come in my `sendToMessage` I want to create `channelPool B` and next time if user group A come in again, i will return `channelPool A`

   - Is it right to try doing this? Is it possible?

---

2. `FixedChannelPool` error handling

   - tell me how can I `FixedChannelPool` error handling? Could I use `acquireTimeoutMillis` over `time.how`?

Here is my code

```
@Service
public class NettyPoolService {

public static final AttributeKey<CompletableFuture<String>> FUTURE = AttributeKey.valueOf("future");
private static final StringDecoder stringDecoder = new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
private static final StringEncoder stringEncoder = new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
private static ChannelPool channelPool;
private static EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;

@Value("${host}")
private String host;

@Value("${port}")
private String port;

@Value("${connection.count}")
private String numberOfConnections;

@Value("${thread.count}")
private String numberOfThreads;


private synchronized void initConnection (String host, int port, int numberOfThreads, int numberOfConnections,String userGroup) {

if ( (channelPool != null) && (eventLoopGroup != null) ) {
return;
}
System.out.println("#############################################");
System.out.println("initConnection start");

eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads);

Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
//bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 32 * 1024);
//bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 8 * 1024);
//bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);

bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).remoteAddress(host, port);

int acquireTimeoutMillis = 10000;
int maxPendingAcquires = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

channelPool = new FixedChannelPool(bootstrap,   
new AbstractChannelPoolHandler() {      

public void channelCreated(Channel ch) throws Exception {
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
// decoders
pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", stringDecoder);

// encoders
pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", stringEncoder);

// business logic handler
pipeline.addLast("clientHandler", new ClientPoolHandler(channelPool));
}
}, 
ChannelHealthChecker.ACTIVE,//eventloop
AcquireTimeoutAction.NEW,   //timeout
acquireTimeoutMillis,       //
numberOfConnections,        //
maxPendingAcquires);        //

System.out.println("initConnection End");
System.out.println("#############################################");



}//initConnection



public void sendToMessage(String message,String GroupId) {

System.out.println("=============GroupId=============:"+GroupId); 
if (channelPool == null) {
initConnection(host, Integer.parseInt(port.trim()), Integer.parseInt(numberOfThreads.trim()), Integer.parseInt(numberOfConnections.trim()) );
}

final CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<String>();
Future<Channel> channelFuture = channelPool.acquire();


System.out.println("=============channelFuture.get()=============:"+channelFuture.toString()); 
channelFuture.addListener(new FutureListener<Channel>() {
public void operationComplete(Future<Channel> f) {
if (f.isSuccess()) {
Channel channel = f.getNow();
channel.attr(NettyPoolClientService.FUTURE).set(future);
channel.writeAndFlush(message, channel.voidPromise());
}
}
});


channelFuture.syncUninterruptibly();


}//sendToBnp
}
```

Comment: The code you have here is a little long. I would advise you split your question in two separate ones. Don't hesitate to create 2 new and close this one. Read [ask] and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) beforehand.